# Can I bind multiple items on a ContextMenuStrip to the same function?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a `ContextMenuStrip` which is populated with Items if some objects in form are visible or not.

When I click on an item of this context menu, a property on the form is changing, according to menu item clicked. I want to access a function in this class which read that property and make some changes in the form.

Some code:

```
private void AddMenuItems(){
    ContextMenuStrip c = new ContextMenuStrip();
    if (extension.Equals("sty") || extension.Equals("st2") || extension.Equals("sst")) {
        this.fileExtension = "style";
        c.Items.Add("Style files (c/u)");
    }    
    if (extension.Equals("txt")){
        this.fileExtension = "text";
        c.Items.Add("Text files (c/u)");
    }
    // some other ifs
    // I've tried this, but only the last one is registered
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem m in c.Items){
        m.Click += CheckSelectedType;
    }
}

private void CheckSelectedType(object sender, EventsArgs e){
    switch(this.fileExtension){
        case "style":
            // do something
            break;
        case "text":
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you have an issue when selecting an existing handler from the component?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I wrote there in the code... only the last one item in menu is registered. If i add 5 items in menu, eachone I clicked only the last one is raised.. Supposing I add "style", "text", "excel","word", and all are registered to the same function, even if I click on "excel", or "style" the event is telling me that the property is "word"

Comment: I see now... it's my fault... this.fileTypes is refreshed by every value...

Comment: I changed it... I store that property `fileExtension` in `Tag` of each menu item, and in `Switch` i check for sender's tag value, and it's working...

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
private ContextMenuStrip CreateContextMenuStrip(string extension)
{
  var result = new ContextMenuStrip();
  if ( extension.Equals("sty") || extension.Equals("st2") || extension.Equals("sst") )
  {
    var item = result.Items.Add("Style files (c/u)");
    item.Tag = "style";
    item.Click += ContextMenuItem_Click;
  }
  else
  if ( extension.Equals("txt") )
  {
    var item = result.Items.Add("Text files (c/u)");
    item.Tag = "text";
    item.Click += ContextMenuItem_Click;
  }
  return result;
}

private void ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  switch ( (string)( (ToolStripItem)sender ).Tag )
  {
    case "style":
      // ...
      break;
    case "text":
      // ...
      break;
  }
}
```